# how to create a record using the after_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models Testimonial and Review.When I create a Testimonial with create_after method I want to create a review with the same testimonial data.

```
class Testimonial < ...
  after_create :create_review

  def create_review
    Review.create(name: self.name, email: self.email,
                  country: self.country, r_status: "No Publicar",
                  testimony: self.testimony)
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
uninitialized constant
```

Here is the full trace:
    vendor/extensions/testimonials/app/models/refinery/testimonials/testimonial.rb:17:in `create_review'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in`block in make_lambda'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in`block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in`_run_create_callbacks'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in`_create_record'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502:in `create_or_update'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in`block in create_or_update'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`_run_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in`create_or_update'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in`save'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in`block (2 levels) in save'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`block in transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in`transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in`with_transaction_returning_status'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in`rollback_active_record_state!'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
    vendor/extensions/testimonials/app/controllers/refinery/testimonials/testimonials_controller.rb:23:in`create'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in`process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in`block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`_run_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in`process'
    actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in`block in action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in`dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block in serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in`method_missing'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block in serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
    dragonfly (1.0.10) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in`call'
    dragonfly (1.0.10) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in`call'
    activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`_run_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
    web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
    quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    dragonfly (1.0.10) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'
    railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in`service'
    /Users/evanx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /Users/evanx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
    /Users/evanx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Can you provide the complete logs? what is the uninitialized constant here?

Comment: @Akarsh I added the full trace.

Comment: Where is the Review model located, I need the complete file path?

Comment: @Akarsh /vendor/extensions/reviews/models/refinery/reviews/review.rb

Answer (score 0):

The Review model belongs to a different module(namespace) from the Testimonial model. The **uninitialized constant error** is coming because you are trying to access a class from outside it's namespace where it is defined. You need to use the ***namespace resolution operator*** (::) to access a class defined in a different namespace.

You need to reference the Review class with it's module like ***Refinery::Reviews::Review*** assuming it's defined as:

```
module Refinery
  module Reviews
    class Review < ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@evanx this is because you have to call the class including the modules.
So here I guess `Refinery::Reviews::Review.create....` should do the trick ! 
Hope it helps ! :)